# Why force vectors between conductors cannot produce a reactionless force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

So this is a concept that I'm pretty sure doesn't make sense, but I wanted to make sure so the idea didn't bother me.  The basic concept is shown around at this point in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhFWarzVmE0

So my reasoning for why this doesn't make sense (from a basic perspective) is that even if conductors angled towards each other can appear to have a net forwards force vector, the forces are only from the conductors pushing on each other, therefore there cannot be any reactionless sort of effect as claimed (or from any other arrangement of conductors with an apparent net force from vector analysis).

Comment: At  what time? this  video seems to be a non mainstream physics pesentation

Comment: Oh, I thought that the link lead to the time as well.  About at 7:30 and for a few minutes onwards then.